# One more incorrect result of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let us consider

```
int = Integrate[ArcSin[Sin[n*x]], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 10]
```

> `-((17 \[Pi]^2)/(4 n)) + ArcSin[Sin[n]] - 1/2 n Abs[Cos[n]] Sec[n]`

This result is not correct in view of the discordance between

```
N[int/.n->55/2]
```

> `12.999`

and

```
Integrate[ArcSin[Sin[55/2*x]], {x, 0, 1}] // N
```

> `0.078822`

Let us correctly calculate the integral under consideration. As

```
n = 55/2; Plot[ArcSin[Sin[n*x]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

shows, the integrand has `Floor[n/2/Pi]` complete waves of the length `2*Pi/n` on the interval
and   one incomplete wave if `n/2/Pi` is not integer. It is clear that the integrals of the integrand
over the complete waves equal zero. Therefore, it is enough to calculate

```
ClearAll[n];res = Integrate[ArcSin[Sin[n*x]], {x, Floor[n/2/Pi]*2*Pi/n, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 10]
```

> `-((17 \[Pi]^2)/(4 n)) + ArcSin[Sin[n]] + (2 \[Pi]^2 Floor[n/(2 \[Pi])]^2)/n - 1/2 n Abs[Cos[n]] Sec[n]`

, but  `res` is not correct in view of

```
N[res /. n -> 55/2]
```

> `24.4837`

, whereas

```
n = 55/2; Integrate[ArcSin[Sin[n*x]], {x, Floor[n/2/Pi]*2*Pi/n, 1}] // N
```

> `0.078822`

Fortunately, there is a workaround. We write down `ArcSin[Sin[x]]` as `Piecewise[{{x, x >= 0 && x <= Pi/2}, {Pi - x,  x >= Pi/2 && x <= 3*Pi/2}, {x - 2*Pi, x >= 3*Pi/2 && x <= 2*Pi}}]` on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.
Then

```
ClearAll[n];res1=Integrate[Piecewise[{{n*x, n*x >= 0 && n*x <= Pi/2}, {Pi - n*x, 
n*x >= Pi/2 && n*x <= 3*Pi/2}, {n*x - 2*Pi, n*x >= 3*Pi/2 && n*x <= 2*Pi}}],
{x, 0, 1 - Floor[n/2/Pi]*2*Pi/n},  Assumptions -> n > 10]
```

> `Piecewise[{{Pi^2/(8*n),  (n - 2*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)] ==  Pi/2 && n > 10) ||  (n - 2*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)] ==  (3*Pi)/2 && n > 10)},  {(n - 2*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)])^2/ (2*n), Inequality[0, Less,  n - 2*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)],  Less, Pi/2] && n > 10},  {(-2*n^2 + 4*n*Pi - Pi^2 +  8*n*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)] -  8*Pi^2*Floor[n/(2*Pi)] -  8*Pi^2*Floor[n/(2*Pi)]^2)/ (4*n), Inequality[Pi/2, Less,  n - 2*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)],  Less, (3*Pi)/2] && n > 10},  {(n^2 - 4*n*Pi + 4*Pi^2 -  4*n*Pi*Floor[n/(2*Pi)] +  8*Pi^2*Floor[n/(2*Pi)] +  4*Pi^2*Floor[n/(2*Pi)]^2)/ (2*n), Inequality[(3*Pi)/2,  Less, n - 2*Pi*Floor[ n/(2*Pi)], Less, 2*Pi] &&  n > 10}}, 0]`

and

```
N[res1 /. n -> 55/2]
```

> `0.078822`

confirms its correctness. Unfortunately,
`Limit[res1,n->Infinity]`
returns the input instead of the expected result `0`.
Is there a way to simplify `res1` or/and to derive another workaround?

Comment: This reads like a bug report (pending confirmation of its correctness) and it should be reported to Wolfram Support, not here. I find that just adding "Is there a workaround?" at the end does not quite make this into an appropriate question.

Comment: @MarcoB: Did you read the question before having posted your comment?  A workaround is presented by me, but I ask for a better one. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need. Your constructive suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I did read the question. The ultimate and most preferable solution to the problem you highlighted would be for Wolfram to fix or improve the internals of Integrate, so everybody could benefit from it. That is why I think it would be best for you to report the issue to Wolfram Support, at least in addition to discussing this question.

Comment: @MarcoB: I did it.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use [`TrigToExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html)

```
int = Assuming[n > 10,
  Integrate[ArcSin[Sin[n*x]] // TrigToExp, {x, 0, 1}] // 
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify]

(* (1/(4 n))(π^2 + 2 Abs[Cos[n]] ArcTan[Abs[Cos[n]], Sin[n]]^2 Sec[n]) *)

int /. n -> 55/2 // Simplify

(* -(55/4) + 9 π - (161 π^2)/110 *)

% // N

(* 0.078822 *)
```

**EDIT:**

The integral is not a continuous function. For the limits the direction must be specified

```
{limFB = Limit[int, n -> 21 Pi/2, 
  Direction -> "FromBelow"], limFB // N}

(* {π/28, 0.1122} *)

{limFA = Limit[int, n -> 21 Pi/2, 
  Direction -> "FromAbove"], limFA // N}

(* {π/84, 0.0373999} *)

Plot[Evaluate@int, {n, 10, 50},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 Exclusions -> ((2 # + 1) Pi/2 & /@ Range[3, 15]),
 ExclusionsStyle -> 
   Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{21 Pi/2, #}], #] & /@ {limFB, limFA}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Thank you. `TrigToExp`  is strong and sure unexpected. Unfortunately, both `(\[Pi]^2 - 2 Abs[Cos[n]] Log[Abs[Cos[n]] + I Sin[n]]^2 Sec[n])/(
 4 n) /. n -> 10*Pi + Pi/2` and `Limit[(\[Pi]^2 - 2 Abs[Cos[n]] Log[Abs[Cos[n]] + I Sin[n]]^2 Sec[n])/(
 4 n), n -> 10*Pi + Pi/2]` produce `Indeterminate`. Hope this gap can be removed.

Comment: Of course, the same issue with `(1/(4 n))(π^2 + 2 Abs[Cos[n]] ArcTan[Abs[Cos[n]], Sin[n]]^2 Sec[n])`.

Comment: Just wander about the graph, how can an integral of continuous function be discontinuous?